# Cocoa osx NSSharingServicePicker set default email address

Tags: macos, cocoa, email, share, items

In my app for Mac I use the NSSharingServicePicker for mailing some items. My problem is that I want to set the default email address to be sent. How can I set this value to show it when the mail client opens??

I have this code:

```
NSMutableArray *shareItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:@"MyText"];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/MyFile.pdf", documentsDirectory];
NSURL* tempFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName];

[shareItems addObject:tempFileURL];

NSSharingServicePicker *sharingPicker = [[NSSharingServicePicker alloc] initWithItems:shareItems];
sharingPicker.delegate = self;
```

This is what I want. I need to set the default destination address in the email.

[image]

Sorry for my poor english. Thanks in advance.

---

SOLVED:

```
-(id<NSSharingServiceDelegate>)sharingServicePicker:(NSSharingServicePicker *)sharingServicePicker delegateForSharingService:(NSSharingService *)sharingService
{

    [sharingService setRecipients:@[@"email@email.com"]];
    [sharingService setSubject:@"MySubject"];

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail` is generally the standard way to achieve this:

```
NSSharingService *service = [NSSharingService sharingServiceNamed:NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail];
service.delegate = self;
service.recipients = @[@"tim.cook@apple.com"];
service.subject = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",NSLocalizedString(@"Re: Requested PDF",nil)];
[service performWithItems:shareItems];
```

It's not exactly clear what you are doing with `NSSharingServicePicker`, although this code can be used with `shareItems`, so the file would be attached along with the body text.

[image]

Comment: Thank u. I use NSSharingServicePicker so that the user can choose the method he wants to share.